# SSIS 2012 (SQL Server Data Tool) how to import data from Ms Access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to import some data from Ms Access to SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012. One of the requirements is to use SSIS so we can generate and schedule a package to run at a later stage.

When I create a Data Flow task, the Source Assistant Wizard is not able to locate the Ms Access database file (accdb). There is no option on the list to select Ms Access or OLE provider. I was able to create a connection to the Access db in Connection Managers but again I cant work out how to use that connection as a data source. Any assistant would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you use a Microsoft Jet OLE DB Providor?

Comment: It is currently going through the OLE 12 Provider I believe. That was how I create the connection in Connection managers

Comment: Can you not just add the Data Source Manually?, right click Data Sources > New (Based on New Connection) > Change Provider to Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB > Filename C:\Database\Database.accdb for example. Then save the connection and in the connection manager right click "New Connection From Data Source" select the datasource and that should be it.

Comment: Thanks I worked it out. Turned out there was a corruption in my SQL installation. Reinstalled the package fix the problem